# how to unselect the normal button in jquery

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to add and delete columns dynamically and i have seen a few stackoverflow answers which suggest to add a remove button at the end of the each row for deletion. but i don't like that approach because the table doesn't look good. And also the table is formed by selecting a grid.

this is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/pr6wd0qv/188/

```
$three.click(function () {
            $('#CreateTableControl tr').click(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color","#FF3700");
                $(this).fadeOut(400, function(){
                $(this).remove();
                return false;
                });
            });
            $("#three").unbind("click");
        });
```

once the delete button is pressed, then on any click on the row, that row gets deleted.  Tried to use unbind(), but didn't work.
Hence please suggest a few other methods to delete a row dynamically.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: i am trying to delete a row, by clicking on that row. A row need to be deleted only when i click on the delete button. but now once the "delete row" button is clicked row gets deleted whenever there is a click on a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't unbind the click on the button, unbind the click on the rows once one has been clicked :

**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/behmzayL/)**

```
$three.click(function () {
    $('#CreateTableControl tr').click(function () {
        $('#CreateTableControl tr').unbind("click"); // unbind here

        $(this).css("background-color","#FF3700");
        $(this).fadeOut(400, function(){
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I have edited my post. See the demo : don't use `$(this)` use `$('#CreateTableControl tr')`

Comment: Why are you using `$('#CreateTableControl tr').unbind("click");` ?

Comment: @ApulGupta To unbind the click on all the `tr`, not just the one that have been clicked (and removed). You could also use `$(this).siblings()` if you want...

Comment: @user3905315 If it helped, you might consider "accept" this answer if you don't mind ;)